# CSS - how to change browser height and have website be unaffected?

Tags: css, responsive

For example, when you change the height of the browser while you're here on Stack Overflow, the content on the page doesn't change. However, if you visit my portfolio: http://seanrobenalt.com/ and change the browser height, some elements get scrunched up. Can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on is that you've set the content as follows:

```
.header-logo {
    background-color: rgba(229,229,229,0.4);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 10vh;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10vh;
}
```

Your height and width are set to `height: 10vh;` respectively `width: 10vh;`.

And what is `vh` short for? It's short for `viewport-height` and`vh` is a measurement unit, but unlike px it's not absolute.

Something that is `10px` in height or width, will ALWAYS be `10px` in height or width, no matter how you resize the window, because we're talking the static physical pixels on your screen.

`vh`, `vw`, or `%` on the other hand are **relative units of measurement.** Take `%` for instance. If you make a div, that is 100% in width – It will stretch the length of the entire parent element. And if the parent element is 100px wide, then the child element will be 100% of 100px which is.... 100px wide. if you set it to 50% of 100px – It's 50px wide.

So what happens if you set an element to `100vw`? It can be simplest described as 100% of the entire browser width – or "Viewport".

So something that is `100vh` will be 100% of **view-height**. (viewport height).

And your image is `10vh`, which means, it will always be 10% of how high the browser window is. So if the browser is resized to be exactly 500px high – Your image will be 50px high.

What you need to do is set the size of the image in px for it always keep it's height and width.

**I suggest you setup a little playground of a few divs, and start playing around with different measurement types.**

Make a few divs that are using `width: 100px;` `height: 200px;` `width: 100%;` `height: 100%;` `width: 100vw;` `height: 100vh;` And place the divs in each other and see what happens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! fixed my site using pixels instead vh and vw. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Make sure to mark the answer correct if you think this was the correct answer to y our question.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating the layout of various elements on your page by using the `vh` (viewport height) unit. `100vh` is equivalent to the height of your browser window at any given moment, so resizing the browser is doing exactly what it was coded to do.

Example element I see inspecting your site:

```
.full-hero {
    background-color: #c7dbfc;
    background-size: cover;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 90vh;
    padding-top: 10vh;
}
```